# How do I maintain a Canon dSLR/phone wi-fi connection when I change shooting modes?

Tags: canon, smartphone, wifi

When using Canon Camera Connect or DSLR Controller app together with my Canon 750D, the wifi connection between my Android smartphone and my camera is lost whenever I change the shooting mode on the camera. Is this intended behaviour? Are there ways to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but after researching the web for quite some bit, it seems that it is how the functionality of the Wi-Fi connection is intended to be.

Hope for changes fixing this in the firmware updates by Canon. Couldn't find a way to submit requests to Canon. If anyone does know a way, do post!